# HTTPS working with DefaultHttpClient on Android

Tags: android, ssl, https

I was using HTTP links with DefaultHttpClient.

After changing all links to HTTPS, I was expecting it to give me some problems like HTTP Error 404 or something.

But it is working just fine.
Can anybody share their experience with the same?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Manan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I got information from the below link

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/sslguide.html